# Replicate pd.concat using pd.merge

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

Is it possible to replicate the following using `pd.merge`

```py
a = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[1,2], y=[5,5]))
b = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[7,7], y=[12,13]))
pd.concat([a,b],axis=1)
```

which outputs

```py
   x  y  x   y
0  1  5  7  12
1  2  5  7  13
```

As this would enable me to add suffixes to the column names.

I expected the following to work:

```py
pd.merge(a, b, how = 'outer',)
```

but this returns:

```py
   x   y
0  1   5
1  2   5
2  7  12
3  7  13
```

i would like the output to be:

```py
   x_l  y_l  x_r   y_r
0  1    5    7    12  
1  2    5    7    13
```

Comment: are you specifically looking for merge method?

Comment: If you want a merge on the index it's possible with `left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=['_l, '_r']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`df.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) too:

```
a.join(b,lsuffix='_l',rsuffix='_r')
```

---

```
   x_l  y_l  x_r  y_r
0    1    5    7   12
1    2    5    7   13
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC fix your `concat` by adding the `keys`

```
s=pd.concat([a,b], axis=1,keys=['l_','r_'])
s.columns=s.columns.map(''.join)
s
   l_x  l_y  r_x  r_y
0    1    5    7   12
1    2    5    7   13
```